# Time complexity using Ford-Fulkerson in network flow

Tags: time-complexity, computer-science, network-flow

I saw that the time cost for network flow using Ford-Fulkerson and BFS/DFS take O(V|E|) such that E is the augmenting path.

If there are variables, student n, teachers m, and assignments l, how can I make the time complexity in terms of n, m and l?

And does O(V|E|) include the running time for the looping parts such as when user inputting the number of students/teachers/assignments?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is the problem you are trying to solve that includes n students, m teachers and I assignments?